# How to Covert Hexadecimal String to readable Number/Decimal Representation (Pressure readout response from RS485 serial device)

Tags: javascript, serial-port, hex, ascii, rs485

So I am working on switching this Ion Gauge (device reads pressure inside of a chamber) from ASCII protocol over to binary protocol (although it actually communicates via hex). This device interfaces with our PC over RS485 Serial Communications. I am using javascript currently to send and receive my ASCII protocol commands.

There is a format for the commands sent, and responses received from the device.
`Length of command send to device = length of response returned`

**Sending a command to the unit:**

```
Byte 0: '!' (hex 0x21) <-- start character
Byte 1: '1' (hex 0x01) <-- address of unit, this is a constant
Byte 2: '2' (hex 0x02) <-- command byte value, this will change as you change commands
Byte 3: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care UNITS
Byte 4: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 1
Byte 5: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 2
Byte 6: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 3
Byte 7: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- dont care data 4
Byte 8: 183 (hex 0xB7) <-- CRC - Carriage return - Not actually typed by user

For testing, this command is physically sent through a serial terminal as: 
'0x21 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7'
```

**RECEIVING a response from the unit:**

```
Byte 0: '*' (hex 0x2A) <-- start character
Byte 1: '1' (hex 0x01) <-- address of unit, this is a constant
Byte 2: '2' (hex 0x02) <-- command byte value, this will change as you change commands
Byte 3: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- UNITS: 0=Torr, 1=Pascals, 2=mBAR
Byte 4: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 1
Byte 5: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 2
Byte 6: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 3
Byte 7: '0' (hex 0x00) <-- floating point byte 4
Byte 8: 148 (hex 0x94) <-- CRC - Carriage return

This response is received as: '2A 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 B7' 
or '0x2A 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7'
(not sure if that's how it actually responds, or if my terminal program automatically formats for readability)
```

So, I am currently communicating with this device over an ASCII protocol, where if I wanted to achieve the above with ASCII commands, I would send for example "#01RDS" to read pressures and I would receive a value like "9.36e-8" as my response. I am switching to the binary protocol/hex commands as there are more useful commands available using that method. How should I go about switching over to this hex code communication? I am using this code in a GUI I am writing in Electron using node.js, vue.js, HTML, and CSS. 
I just want to be able to properly convert the responses from the device to a readable format that I can easily use to perform actions/trigger functions based on the decimal point values in those responses. 
I am unsure of how to handle the data, as it comes in as the `2A 01 02 00 00 00 00 00 B7` format.
I want the program to think along the lines of:

```
 - Check if the first byte (byte 0) contains the start character '!' --> Byte0 = 2A --> Proceed
  - Check Byte3 units, if 0 --> units = Torr, Proceed
  - Check and store values of Byte4-Byte7
  - Convert Hex values of floating point bytes4-7 to Decimal,   etc
```

If anyone has any tips on how I can approach this I would be very appreciative. See the manual below for more insight on how the communication works.

Link to the Operation Manual for the specific device I am working with:
`https://www.lesker.com/newweb/gauges/pdf/manuals/392usermanual.pdf`

```
*PDF pg. 59: RS485 Serial Communicatoins - Binary Protocol
*PDF pg. 61: Notes when using Binary Protocol
*PDF pg. 62: RS485 Commands Summary
```

Comment: see the radix part of parseInt(str,radix)

Comment: Okay, I'm checking that out now. Looks like a step in the right direction, however I am a bit of a JS noob and still learning as I go, so still a little unclear how I should proceed. I'm pretty good at figuring things out as I move along, my issue is more `starting` , lol

Comment: *"binary protocol (although it actually communicates via hex)"* -- No, it's a binary protocol and actually communicates via binary values.  Humans represent the binary using hexadecimal notion for convenience.  Newbies also use "hex" to refer to ASCII text of hexadecimal digits, so your mention of "hexadecimal string"  is doubly confusing.  *"CRC - Carriage return"* -- No, a `CRC `is a calculated value using a polynomial, whereas a `carriage return` is a fixed code value.  One is used with binary protocol; the other is used with ASCII text protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the question in the title:

1. If `hexString` is a string of hexadecimal digit pairs,

   ```
   let binArray = hexSring.match(/../g).map( hex=> parseInt(hex,16));
   ```

   converts the string into an array of unsigned integers in range [0-255], with inverse logic
2. If `binArray` is an array of unsigned integers in range [0-255],

   ```
   let hexString = binArray.map( byte=>byte.toString(16).padStart(2,'0')).join('');
   ```

   converts the array into a string of hex character pairs starting with the first array entry.

**Are they needed?**

This answer originally described binary prototcol messages being converted into a stream of hex digit pairs for transmission over the RS-485 communicatins link. This was based on the questtion reporting that (some kind of) hex output from the pressure gauge was displayed on a terminal, and an additional note on page 59 of in the manual saying

> 2. The messages sent to the unit and received from the unit are sent in hexadecimal,...

Comment on this answer pointed out that the binary protocol "messages" are documented in other places in the manual  as if sent directly over the RS485 link as binary bytes with no conversion to hex.

I concur this is likely the case with "sent in hexadecimal" meant to be understood as "sent as binary bytes", leaving the binary/hex conversions above for reference only.

**More on the binary protocol**

1. A binary message is a sequence of 8 binary bit bytes (or "octets") ending in an 8 bit Cyclic redundancy Check byte calculated from the preceding message bytes. (A property of the CRC value is that applying the CRC calculation to the entire message, including the CRC8 byte on the end, produces a result of zero if no transmission error occurred.)
2. Carriage returns appear to be part of the ASCII protocol and I found no mention of their use in binary messages in the manual (please recheck in practice).
3. The expected length of a reply is the same as that sent.
4. If a binary byte represents an ASCII character, its numeric value is the ASCII character code for the character. E.G.

   ```
   '*'.charCodeAt(0)
   ```

   converts an asterisk to the number 42 (decimal), and

   ```
   String.fromCharCode( 42)
   ```

   converts the number 42 to an asterisk.
5. Converting floating points is trickier. The method I've used in the snippet is to put the 4 floating point byte values into a `Uint8` typed array and then used the arrays buffer to create a `Float32` typed array from which the first element can be retrieved as a (floating point) number. The correctness depends on which order the fp bytes are held in the message (little or big endian) and testing with zero doesn't reveal which - you may have to reverse the order of bytes for JavaScript (hopefully not). Using a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) could be another way of doing it. I am also assuming the instrumentation provides 32 bit floating point values using the same standards as JavaScript (they have been around a while).

This example looks at decoding a received message example, `2A0102000000000094` in hex. The CRC8 function has been translated from the C version provided in the manual, and modified to accept an array of byte values and calculate the CRC for all bytes provided in the call:

```js
function calculate_CRC8( uint8Array) {
    var CRC_Value;
    var Counter;
    var BitCounter;
    var XOR_Byte;
    var TransmitByte;

    // Initialize the local variable.
    CRC_Value = 0xFF;
    
    // Calculate the CRC.
    for(Counter = 0; Counter < uint8Array.length; Counter++) {
        TransmitByte = uint8Array[ Counter];
        BitCounter = 8;
    
        while(BitCounter != 0) {
            BitCounter--;
            XOR_Byte = TransmitByte ^ CRC_Value;
            if((XOR_Byte & 0x80) != 0) {
                CRC_Value ^= 0x0E;
                CRC_Value <<= 1;
                CRC_Value |= 1;
            }
            else{
                CRC_Value <<= 1;
            }
    
            // Left shift the calculation byte.
            TransmitByte <<= 1;
            // keep CRC to 8 bits (not needed in C)
            CRC_Value &= 0xff;  
        }
    }
    // Return the calculated CRC value.
    return(CRC_Value);
}

/**********  Example to check received message   ********/

// Only if Encoded as Hexadecial digits:
// let hexReceived = "2A0102000000000094"; // without <CR>
// convert hexString to 8 bit integers in range [0, 255]
// let binReceived = hexReceived.match(/../g).map( hex=> parseInt(hex,16));

let binReceived = [0x2a, 1, 2, 0,0,0,0,0, 0x94];  // binary protocol byte values

console.log( "binReceived: ", binReceived)

// check CRC of binary bytes, including sent CRC, reduces to zero
let CRC = calculate_CRC8( binReceived);
if( CRC) {
    // handle Error
 throw new Error( "bad CRC at end of " + hexReceived);
}

// extract fp value

let bytes = binReceived.splice (4,4);  // 4 byte Array
// reverse byte order if in wrong order!!!!

let buffer = Uint8Array.of.apply(Uint8Array, bytes).buffer;
console.log( "buffer: ", buffer)

let fp = new Float32Array( buffer) [0];

console.log( "message start '%s', address %s, command %s, units %s, value %s",
   String.fromCharCode(binReceived[0]),
   binReceived[ 1],
   binReceived[ 2],
   ["TORR", "PASCALS", "mBAR"][ binReceived[3]],
   fp
);

/************* Example to encode a command to send *********/

// Example command to read gauge 1's IG pressure

let cmdBytes = [
   '!'.charCodeAt(0), // start character
   1,                 // instrument address
   2,                 // Read IG Pressure command
   0,                 // xx units
   0,0,0,0            // xxxxxxxx float32 value (zero)
];

// calculate and add CRC

cmdBytes.push( calculate_CRC8( cmdBytes));

console.log("/* Send command example*/");
console.log("Bytes to read IG pressure from gauge 1: ", cmdBytes);

// send cmdBytes to the gauge...
```

To send a command using the `calculateCRC8` JavaScript function above,

- assemble the binary bytes of the command in an array without the CRC,
- calculate the CRC of the command bytes by calling `calculateCRC8` with an array containing just the command bytes - the return value is their computed CRC8 check value.
- append the CRC8 value to the array,
- send all of the array bytes to the instrument.

Comment: In the code above, where should I be loading the command string I want to send into the CRC function to caluclate the required CRC to send the message to the unit? Would I need to load the '0x2A 0x01 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xB7' into 'TransmitByte' ?

Comment: The CRC8 byte value is calculated on the binary octets  of the command before being converted to hex. See the updated code snippet for an example.

Comment: Thank you! I am still not seeing where you are loading the command to send into the CRC8 function. I see that you have `cmdBytes.push( calculate_CRC8( cmdBytes));` but I don't see where you are taking the command bytes and loading them into a variable within the CRC8 function? Maybe I'm just too much of a JS noob, but theres no variable `cmdBytes` within the `calculateCRC8' function.

Comment: `TransmitByte` is a local variable name in the `calculateCRC8` function, chosen by the author of the C function to calculate the CRC8 value provided in the user manual. You don't "load" anything into it, you just call the function. `cmdBytes` is a variable name I used to refer to an array of bytes in the example. You may need to learn more programming for it to become clearer.

Comment: *"A message is composed of a string of hex character pairs"* -- Wrong, the binary protocol does not use *"characters"*.  *"convert the entire array to a string of hex pairs"* -- This is wrong.  A binary protocol does not require a conversion to *"hex character pairs"*.